# How to organise listbox with a scrollbar using grids

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I am trying to plan a GUI that's going to use  list boxes with scrollbars and I'm learning the grid system to organise. From what iv'e read each widget needs to go in a separate grid cell.So does that mean the list box goes in one grid cell and the scrollbar in another. This is the simple example I am trying to get to work but the scroll bar not extending as it should be.
So if i need 6 lists and each with scroll bar does that mean i need 12 columns and 6 rows ?
Code below for the test for one list with scrollbar not working - any advice please.thanks

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

my_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11',
           '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20']

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
# scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1)

listbox = Listbox(root)
# listbox.pack()
listbox.grid(row=0, column=0)

for item in my_list:
    listbox.insert(END, item)

# attach listbox to scrollbar
listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

found the solution sticky='ns' inserted in scrollbar.grid line